# how to read a binary file one line at a time in java

Tags: java, file, binary

I need to read binary data from a file one line at a time. But it seems I can only read n bytes at a time using FileInputStream, any suggestions?

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/dir/testfile");
byte[] buffer = new byte[3480];
inputStream.read(buffer);
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "line" in a binary file. It's either a single "thing" or it has a specific, documented format based on records / fields that tells you how many bytes to read for each.

Comment: And when you read, it is essential to store the return value in a variable, test it for -1, and otherwise use it as the length of the data in the buffer. The read() method isn't obliged to fill the buffer.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "line".  If there's some special byte used as a separator (like `\n`), you'll probably have to do the hard work yourself (i.e. searching for the byte, extracting the desired part of the array with `Arrays.copy`, putting subarrays together if they're in different buffers), unless there's some helpful methods I don't know about.

Comment: @ajb It can't be a special character in a binary file unless there is also an escape convention so it can appear as data.

Comment: @EJP Perhaps.  We really have no idea what kind of file he's trying to work with.

Comment: @ajb No 'perhaps' about it. It's a fact. If the line terminator character is reserved, you can read lines. If it isn't, it's a binary file. I doubt the OP knows what the file is either.

Answer (score 3):

Binary files don't have lines. Therefore you can't read lines.

Comment: First version was better.

Comment: I edited it twice... This is the first version.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a "line" in a binary file.

It's either a single "thing" or it has a specific, documented format based on records / fields that tells you how many bytes to read for each (or how they're terminated) and what they represent.

(moved from comment)